# add an image as a icon in _site.yml

Tags: r, r-markdown, icons

I have something like [this](https://rstudio4edu.github.io/rstudio4edu-book/rmd-dress.html#rmd-icons) and I want to add an image.png as an icon. Where the image icon should have the same width and length as fontawesome icons. Many thaks in advance.

```
name: my-website
output_dir: docs
navbar:
  title: My Website
  left:
  - text: Home
    href: index.html
  - text: About
    href: about.html
  - text: Readings
    icon: DIRECTORY.OF.MY.IMAGE.PNG
    menu:
    - text: Module 1
      icon: fa-pepper-hot # ICON IN THE DROPDOWN MENU IS NOT WORKING.
      href: readings-module1.html
    - text: Module 2
      href: readings-module2.html
    - text: Module 3
      href: readings-module3.html
    - text: Module 4
      href: readings-module4.html
output:
  html_document:
    theme: yeti
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add your custom CSS that has rules to replicate fontawesome icons settings for your PNG image.

Comment: Could you please show how to do this?